# What is the best way to continuously (every 10-20 seconds) import a remote XML (accessible through HTTP) into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, parsing, import

I have a remote XML file, which is zipped (approx 100MB in size). I need to download, extract, read, parse and import into SQL Server.

Before starting coding this solution (in Python), is there any ready-made utility which could do that? Notice that this needs to run on a scheduled basis (preferably as service) or Windows Schedule.

What's really important is that it needs to be really fast!

Thank you,
Giorgoc

Comment: I would start looking at SSIS first. You can set up a package to import the XML and load it into your SQL Server database and i.m.o. would be the simplest and quickest.. Then, using the job agent, you can call the package based on an interval... eg: every 10 to 20 seconds.

Comment: what do you mean 'set up a package' to import XML? Can a 'package' download, extract and then import ??

Comment: Hi Giorgoc, an SSIS package (like a container) can do many built in tasks and can also access c# scripts. It will be possible to download the XML file, extract and transform the data, and then load it into a SQL Server table. You can do this all in one package or split the tasks out into multiple packages which would be better for debugging i.m.o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on my comments:

You can quite easily do this with SSIS.

1. Download the remote XML file... Here is an example: [How to read a remote xml file from SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238229/how-to-read-a-remote-xml-file-from-sql-server-2005)
2. you can then do transformation on the data if needed by using transformation tasks
3. Using SSIS to load the XML data into the SQL Server DB... Here is an example: [How to load an XML file into a database using an SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152671/how-to-load-an-xml-file-into-a-database-using-an-ssis-package)

Hope they point you in the right direction and help you in your tasks.